# Inserting Default Value In Not Null or Null Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am just confused:

I have this table and I want to ensure that the `UserName` column is never null, and if there is null in the insert, then apply the default value.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
[UserID] [CHAR](5) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [VARCHAR](12) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_UserName DEFAULT 'Visitor')
```

If the insert statement contain no username, then I want to insert a default value.

Running this gives me an error:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
           ([UserID]
           ,[UserName])
     VALUES
           ('12345',
           NULL)
```

If make the column null, then I get null if there is a null value despite the default.

I can't seem to find an explanation, [I read stuff here on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=8CJkcT8-HTQC&pg=PT393&lpg=PT393&dq=TSQL%20Insert%20default%20if%20no%20value%20provided&source=bl&ots=7t5XhOj9tc&sig=-xgQguFsT7GnaD1omG2Am70rdI0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hYgsU4CNL8PlyAGgzYH4Dg&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=TSQL%20Insert%20default%20if%20no%20value%20provided&f=false).

I could also use CASE WHEN in an insert statement but I hate to mask my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to exclude the column:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ([UserID]) VALUES ('12345')
```

or provide the `default` keyword like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ([UserID], [UserName]) VALUES ('999', DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Okay, So if I am using an `INSERT` with `SELECT` I am going to need a `CASE WHEN` or some kind of condition. Right?
Example: `INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ([UserID], [UserName])
Select UserID = '12345', UserName = CASE WHEN UserName IS NULL THEN 'Visitor' END`

Answer (score 1):

To insert the default into that column, don't specify the column in the insert. The constaint will be applied if nothing is specified for the column, which is **different** that explicitly specifying null. You can do ISNULL(val,'Visitor') to get the behavior you want in your insert script.i.e.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
       ([UserID])
 VALUES
       ('12345')
```

If you want to pull in variable that can be null:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
       ([UserID], [UserName])
 VALUES
       ('12345', ISNULL(@SomeVariable, 'Visitor'))
```

Will give you what you want. In this case you don't need the constraint.

Comment: But there are other users with UserName, so not specifying the column in the insert will always yield the default. I only need default if the Username is null. What happens if I am inserting from another table which contain some null values?